# Controlling Youtube Video on iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

**What I want:**

- Ability to seek to specific point of a *Youtube* video.
- Ability mute/unmute a *Youtube* video.
- Ability to play and pause a *Youtube* video.

**What I know:**

- I can't get url of youtube videos to play in native player.
- I can get embed code (HTML) from REST services.

I have read documentation of *Youtube* REST services and I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Is this even possible? If so, in which direction I should go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIWebView` to play youtube video with required functionality.

here is example

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
                            @"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head><body style=\"background:#000;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"",
                            youTubeUrl,
                            @"?f=gdata_videos&rel=0\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"",
                            youTubeUrl,
                            @"?f=gdata_videos&rel=0\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\" ",
                            width,
                            @"\"height=\" ",
                            height,
                            @"\"></embed></object></div></body></html>"];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [_youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nill]];
```

Comment: How can I play/pause/mute/unmute/seek?

Comment: This will give you a player which contains the required functions

Comment: load that embed code in UIWebView and it will do the rest.